# Tag for low hardware requirements?

Tags: discussion, tags

Several questions deal with the requirement "should run on old hardware". Would a tag for low hardware requirements add a value here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not really convinced so. "Old hardware" is relative - I've currently got a core2duo I consider slow and old, but I've also fixed up even older hardware. What's old hardware is also relative and a bit of a sliding scale with time.

I'd say the question requirements should cover it.

Comment: I agree. Even if we'd name it differently (something like minimal-resource-requirements), the meaning would not persist. I remember how happy I was getting additional 4 MB (sic!) RAM for my i386 back then #) // So right, this should be specified with the question's requirements, and *could* additionally be highlighted with the title.